# Adding Inline Search function to web page

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to embed an inline search box into a web page which provides similar functionality to the [IE7Pro Inline Search](http://www.ie7pro.com/inline-search.html) or similar plugins for Firefox/Safari?

Comment: Just a note. You don't need a plugin to do this in Firefox. It's built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery inline search plugin](https://github.com/hmert/inline-search) provides this functionality

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are asking if it is possible to allow a user to type in a query that will search the text of page they are on?

You can certainly do that.  I would suggest looking into one of the javascript libraries, [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is my library of choice, for your functionality.  It has a rich selector syntax that allows you to search various parts of the page easily and without worrying about cross-browser coding yourself.